# One column has repeated textual values, other numerical values. Find all numerical values corresponding to searched textual value. Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

formula to list all numerical values corresponding to either NORTH-1, NORTH-2, or NORTH-3.

tried INDEX MATCH combination without any result. IFERROR INDEX SMALL IF ROW() ROWS(). The requirement is to list the corresponding numerical values in a single column.

Comment: FILTER() is probably what you want.

Comment: Thank You Mr Scott Craner. The problem with Filter() is that it also lists textual values whereas the requirement is that the formula should only list the corresponding numerical values.

Comment: The output can differ from the criteria: `=FILTER(B:B,A:A="NORTH-1")`

Comment: Now I equate only the numerical column to another column and use the new column for my calculations. Thanks again :)

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is resolved. Great help :)

Answer (score 1):

### Matching Data To Columns (Pivot)

[image]

```
=LET(Data,A2:B21,rCol,1,aCol,2,
    dr,INDEX(Data,,rCol),da,INDEX(Data,,aCol),
    h,TOROW(SORT(UNIQUE(dr))),
    d,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(h)),LAMBDA(rr,c,
        IFERROR(HSTACK(rr,FILTER(da,dr=INDEX(h,,c))),""))),,1),
VSTACK(h,d))
```